# MVC and titanium, structure

Tags: javascript, iphone, model-view-controller, titanium, titanium-mobile

Views and controller,

In titanium do you normally have 1 controller per view? or 1 controller per group of views?

You have a form, PageX_Detail, PageX_Confirm, and PageX_Results.

In this case would you create 3 views and 3 controllers or 3 views and 1 controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's best to have one controller per the group of views.

Titanium applications currently don't typically follow a strict MVC structure (although Appcelerator is working on an MVC framework for use with Titanium called [Alloy](https://github.com/appcelerator/alloy)).

The most popular ways to organize Titanium applications that I've discovered are:

1) The [Tweetanium](https://github.com/appcelerator-titans/tweetanium/tree/master/mobile/Tweetanium) style, where a global namespace contains application-wide functionality and a main window hosts each application view.

Or, my favorite (and the most Appcelerator-supported way),

2) The CommonJS approach and the use of `require()` instead of the deprecating `Ti.include()`

Comment: thanks, btw in regards to views, do you create a view (UI definition) for each specific platform iphone, android etc, or 1 common view for all platforms?

Comment: I believe it's best practice under the CommonJS methodology to create separate views for each platform (i.e. have an Android folder for Android views and an iOS folder for iOS views)